# Any good examples of a user signing up for a Browser Certificate / Client Certificate?

Tags: login, security, signup-signon

A client certificate is something that is used with TLS/SSL to increase security of the HTTPS session. There are two parts to this

1. The user needs to create the certificate, have it approved (which is either instant or may be delayed), and download the cert.
2. During the sign in process, the user is prompted to select a certificate

There is a known bug with this process that makes Chrome incompatible with browser certificates of any type, even though Chrome supports the required `<keygen/>` HTML5 element.

Question:

Is there any good example of what this process should look like (enrollment and usage) for sites that need the utmost of security for a HTTPS session?

Comment: Are you able to share a wireframe of how you imagine this working? It's probably not a process with which we're all familiar.

Comment: I'll post a link to a working sample site as soon as NetOps opens up the firewall

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers support directly passing a certificate back to the browser.  [StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com) is the site I use for the SSL certificates for my site and they do a nice job of using the built in functionality of browsers to handle client certificate issuance securely.

Basically the user just clicks a button to get the certificate and the server generates and provides one for them.  If any validation needs to be done of the user's identity, that can be handled separately before the user's certificate is considered valid for the sensitive actions.

Comment: I checked there and only see server side SSL, not client side certs for mutual authentication.

Comment: @makerofthings7 They issue a client side cert as their user registration.  You actually only have a client certificate to represent your account.  Basic user registration is free.

Comment: @makerofthings7 - Also, I think this is the first time I've run in to someone I recognize from Security on another portion of the network (at least on a topic that wasn't migrated)

Comment: ha! It's good to see you're here!